# How is it better to create a macros and apply it to a changing set of xlsx files?

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is the following. I want to have a macro that I will apply to a constantly extending bunch of .xlsx files. I don't have macros inside those files (I download them), I can't change it in any way. But I have a script and I want it to be applied to an .xlsx file

Should it be a `.vbs` file? If so, how do I address a workbook?

Comment: @FaneDuru, you asked me to tag you here. 
My initial question was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216795/run-a-vbs-script-for-an-xlsx-file-from-cmd?noredirect=1#comment115298403_65216795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the advantage to see your previous question on a similar issue...

So, a script example able to find a specific workbook in an Excel open session and write in some cells, may look like the following one:

```
dim objEx, wb, myWb, sh, wbName, mySheet, boolFound 

myWB = "mock_data_template.xlsx"
mySheet = "data"
set objEx = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
if not objex is nothing then
    msgbox "Excel session open"
    for each wb in objEx.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = wbName then            
            set myWb = wb:boolFound = true: exit for
        end if
    next
    if boolFound then
        msgbox "myWorkbook open"
        set sh = mywb.Sheets(mySheet)
        if not sh is nothing then
            msgbox "my sheet exists"
            sh.Range("G2").Value = 1
            sh.Range("G3").Value = 2
            sh.Range("G4").Value = 3
        end if
    else
        msgbox "Workbook not found"
    end if
else
    msgbox "No Excel session open"
end if
```

This is just an example to show you how such a simple task can be handled with VBScript. But this can also be handled in Excel, writing a macro to do something similar. Even simpler...

Now, the above code shows you how an Excel **existing** session can be found and then how to handle workbooks, worksheets, ranges etc. But it can be extended to open such a session and a specific workbook in that new session, then doing what the actual code does. It will only need the workbook full path, like an extra variable. If interested, i can adapt it for such an alternative, too.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll take a detailed look at it.